# is it possible to add a tasks timeline to a sharepoint communications site

Tags: sharepoint-online, timeline, communication-site

I am trying to add a tasks timeline to a sharepoint communications site, but I can't see how.

is this possible and if so how would I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want to show the tasks in timeline in task list?

If that’s the case, go to tasks list->select the tasks->TASKS ribbon->Add to timeline.